# Когда осуществляется запись на диск без close/fsync?

Tags: c, linux, unix, файловая-система

Допустим, есть программа, которая вызвала write(). Затем ушла в вечный цикл без вызова close() или fsync()/sync(). В каком случае произойдет реальная запись данных на диск? Файловая система без барьеров, паралельные процессы sync() не вызывают.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Информация из write() попадает в "грязные" страницы кэша (Dirty). Через некоторое время (стандартно каждые 5 секунд = `/proc/sys/vm/dirty_writeback_centisecs / 100`) ядро проверяет не пора ли что записывать из грязных страниц. Ядро записывает страницы прождавшие более `/proc/sys/vm/dirty_expire_centiseconds` времени (стандартно 30 секунд) либо раньше, если осталось мало свободной памяти. Точнее второе условие задаётся в виде: `Dirty * 100 / (MemFree + Cached - Mapped) > /proc/sys/vm/dirty_background_ratio` либо `Dirty > /proc/sys/vm/dirty_background_bytes` в зависимости от того какой параметр установлен.

Кроме этого предусмотрен ещё крайний случай: когда грязный кэш разрастается больше `/proc/sys/vm/dirty_ratio` процентов от доступной памяти (MemFree + Cached - Mapped) либо больше `/proc/sys/vm/dirty_bytes`, то все процессы выполняющие запись приостанавливаются до фактической записи их данных (блокирующая запись).

Источники: https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/sysctl/vm.txt
http://www.westnet.com/~gsmith/content/linux-pdflush.htm

Comment: Отлично. Теперь легко запомнить что и где гуглить, когда потребуется вспомнить где в /proc эти параметры, а то в man 5 proc что-то они отсутствуют.